# Do i have to call IUnknown.Release/clean up com objects on process exit?

Tags: c++, com

I know operating system handles automatically closed on process exit, but say if i have a surrogate for Excel/Visual Studio, do i have to call release on them on process exit to cleanup/let them later terminate safely not thinking they are used by someone?
Is it same for IConnectionPoint and other objects, and what about registered events? Will excel try to continue to notify? Releasing connection point itself removes all events?

Comment: You have to manually release COM interfaces, yes.  Better to use smart pointers that can handle that for you, like `CComPtr` or `_com_ptr_t` or other equivalent class.

Comment: what if i dont or cant like unexpected crashes?

Comment: All COM objects are reference-counted. They are destroyed only when their refcount is decremented to 0. If you don't call `Release()` (directly or indirectly), the refcount will not be decremented properly. Now, in the case of an out-of-process server, your client app is actually acting on a **proxy** object, the live object is inside the server process. The system will handle cleaning up the proxy *eventually* if your client terminates unexpectedly, but it is possible that the server won't detect that for a while, so if it tries to communicate with your client afterwards, it might still fail.

Comment: how does system know if i hold a proxy? i suspect events are unsubscribed because cookie value is not decreasing but not sure.

Comment: "*how does system know if i hold a proxy?*"- the system is the one that created it in the first place and gave it to you. "*i suspect events are unsubscribed*" - depends on the implementation

Comment: i just wondered mechanism. does it hook to process exit or use special os handles etc. according to events, say default implementation mechanisms provided by atl.

Comment: The *HOW* is a private implementation detail of the system. Some details are on MSDN, but basically the system will know if the connection between the proxy object and the live object has been severed. Any further communication attempts through the proxy will fail with an appropriate error code until the system can cleanup what's left over.

Comment: probably its using named pipes which is/has os handle .i cant upvote because im new member but Thanks

Comment: @RemyLebeau according to this ms example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example-creating-a-wmi-application you have to cleanup before shutdown. is it because time of os cleanup is undeterministic?

Comment: that example is not what we've been discussing. But it does go back to my earlier comment that you must `Release()` any COM interface you obtain to avoid leaks.

Comment: that example is what question was all about. in proc memory will already be cleaned up. if os informs server proc, sooner or later it will be cleared too. so how leaks are possible plus it may happen unexpected crushes.